# surge suppression

Tags: surge-protection

I have a single phase circuit with 120VAC L and N. This is going through a step up transformer to up the Voltage to circa 1500VAC. question is how and where to connect the surge suppression devices? ie on the 120V side of the XFMR or do they have to be on the 1500VAC side?

Also I have a distribution system like a PDU upstream of the 120VAC supply to the XMFR, could the surge suppression be in there?

Comment: Can you please give us some more context here? If you're only concerned about mains power input surges, then a 120VAC suppressor pretty much anywhere upstream of your xfmr would be sufficient. However, if you're asking a question about something you're building where a surge suppression device is required by an applicable elec. code (or other legal/liability concern), then we'd need to see that code in order to answer correctly.

Comment: I don't believe there are any specific code requirements its purely to protect the downstream equipment from mains surges. Codes are NFPA70, API 17F or ISO 13628-6

Answer (score 1):

Purely for protecting downstream equipment from mains surges, a 120VAC suppressor pretty much anywhere upstream of the xfmr should be sufficient (so long as it's rated for the full load the xfmr draws, of course). Most surge suppressors work by shorting surge current from L to N, or from L to GND, so the further upstream you place them, the fewer components between surge origin & surge suppressor can be damaged (such as the windings in your xfmr when the surge suppressor effectively shorts the secondary windings, allowing momentary huge currents in both primary & secondary windings).

Comment: i'm not sure I fully understand what you mean about it being rated for the full load the xfmr draws? xfmr is rated at 2.5kVA at a 300V tap so max current is about 8.33A but the breaker protecting this branch is set at 20A because of the other stuff involved also but i'm looking at using phoenix contact possibly something like 280067 or 2804429. I don't really understand the operation or how to size these etc.

Comment: Well, one digit is missing from the first model you listed (280067_), but the 2804429 is for 240/415 volt (full single-phase, or 3-phase) usage, rather than for (split-phase) 120 volt circuits. It could still work, but would be "overkill" at the least, and at most require installing a new "secondary" breaker box to split down the 240V circuit into 2 120V circuits. As for the "full load the xfmr draws" part, most transformers operate at ~80% efficiency @ rated capacity, so a 2.5KVA rated xfmr should draw around ~3.2KVA, so any surge protector rated for >=4KVA should suffice (with safety margin)

Comment: apologies, 2800675

Comment: Ok, that one's rated to protect up to an 80A load on a 120V circuit (or ~9.6KVA), but I just noticed a discrepancy between your 2.5KVA transformer rating & your OP statement about using a 120V primary. To get 2.5KVA from a 120V source requires >20A current, even before adding any losses, so either your primary windings are on a 240V circuit, of your xfmr is capable of overloading your 20A circuit before it reaches its rated load.

Comment: Where / how did you get the 80A and the 9.6KVA from? I don't see those numbers anywhere on the data sheet?                                                                                  in ref to the discrepancy, Are you are referring to the P=IV where P=2500 and V=120 I=20.83A? or something different?

Comment: https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?urile=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2800675 click on the "technical data" tab, then the "protection circuit" link to see "Nominal Voltage=120V" and "Rated Load Current=80A) 120V*80A=9600VA=9.6KVA : : As for the discrepancy; yes, that's exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: ah ok I have an old printed catalog i'll check out the website.  As for the discrepancy then yes, the breaker will trip before we reach full rated load. it didn't seem worthwhile upping the mcb /wiring etc to be capable for full load when in reality our application we will never be at or require full load. our operational figures are considerably less than the rated values.

Comment: In light of that info (operational current never above 120V/20A loading), that 2800675, according to specs, should be quite sufficient.

Comment: even at the rated values its still ok though right? if its good for 9.6kVA? ok so just to add something else into the mix now, say I had two xfmr's off the upstream dist unit, ie the 120V/30A feed where im planning on putting this surge device and that feed was then dist to two individual 20amp breakers, and two 2.5kVA xfmrs, im assuming the surge device would need to be rated for 5KVA in this case? right? and similarly for more ie 3 / 4 etc ?

Comment: I would personally prefer to keep about 4KVA of surge protection device capacity for every 2.5KVA of rated xfmr output, as explained in my first comment under this answer. As for your 2nd question, since the surge protector you're considering is rated for ~9.6KVA, it should have no problem handling 2 such xfmrs (even using my preferred "safety margin" of 4KVA each, that still leaves another 1.6KVA of capacity "in reserve").

Comment: I think I will try and find a smaller surge suppressor circa 4kVA as you mentioned above per 2.5kVA xmfr. Or if you have any suggestions let me know please. You also got me thinking about the MCB tripping before the full rated load of the xfmr the other day, so I went back and checked what we have there. Turns out the wiring and the feed wire for the 30A input is 10AWG so good for 55A, and post 20A breaker to ea xfmr is 14awg so good to 32A so it actually looks like we can rate the MCB for xfmr full load after all. The next question is what to go to? next readily available size is 25A?

Comment: 25A should be fine for a MCB if your local code allows 32A through your distro. wires (my code only allows 15A through 14ga wires, and 30A through 10ga wires). -- If you're more concerned, however, about preserving the xfmrs (rather than just avoiding electrical fires), you could stick with the 20A breakers to ensure that any damaging currents to the xfmr get cut off.

Comment: I'll need to pull the local code and double check. also, if I was to put a 120/120VAC isolation Xfmr upstream of the dist and the 2 x 2.5kva xfmrs would that help any? and would it need to be sized for the load of both xfrms or how would I size it?

Comment: The major effects of an isolating xfmr are DC bias (NOT surge/spike/lightning/transients) removal by shorting DC to ground, at the cost of a ~20% loss in efficiency. I don't see any major benefit to your step-up xfmrs by using such a device (especially since your mains power is probably coming from utility pole-mounted xfmrs a few dozen feet outside of the building). - - Everyone has their own opinion, but that's mine ;)